# Epson XP-7100 all-in one Scanner not recognized

Tags: scanner

Printer works just fine, HP all-in-one works just fine except for blurred print. Downloaded everything imaginable but still nothing.I do not beleive that the Epson scanner and Ubuntu 19.10 were made to work together.
Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Did you doenload and install Epson Linux drivers among "everything imaginable"?

Answer (score 0):

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult install everything and it worked (with gscan2pdf) fine in 19.10.
But I have problem with adf on 20.04 so wait to before updating.